# I have a signup issue with linking a submit button to a new page

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a signup form to a website and I am trying to link the signup form with the next page of the sign up. I am using MySQL to make a database to store the forms details.

Here is the code

```
<div id="Login Box"class="center" style="font-family:Century;color:white;
     font-size:20px;text-align:center;background-color:red;height:400px;width:600px;">
  Enter a new username and password to register.

    <br>
    <br>
<?php   
$con=mysqli_connect("UserDirectory.ini");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

    // Create database
$sql="CREATE DATABASE UserDirectory";
CREATE TABLE Customer (
  id  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email     VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
  create_date   DATETIME    NOT NULL,
  password      VARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL,
  Username      VARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL,
?>

<?php
 dbstuff.inc
define("DBHOST", "YOURHOST");
define("DBUSERNAME", "YOURUSERNAME");
define("DBPASS", "YOURPASSWORD");
define("DB","UserDirectory"); 
?>

<form id="gaia_registerform" method="post" action=>
Username: <input type="text" name="usrname">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>

    <br>
    <br>    

Password: <input type="password" name="pwd">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $pwdErr;?></span>

    <br>
    <br>

Email: <input type="email" name="Email">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>

    <br>
    <br>

<input id="Continue" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" name="Continue"  type="submit" value="Continue" action="retropcpersonalinfo.html" method="link" </input>
</form>

    <br>
    <br>

<a href=retropc.html>Cancel</a>
```

Comment: Is this complete block of code? Your markup is invalid `<form id="gaia_registerform" method="post" action=>` action attribute is blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sequence:

```
// Create database
$sql="CREATE DATABASE UserDirectory";
CREATE TABLE Customer (
  id  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email     VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
  create_date   DATETIME    NOT NULL,
  password      VARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL,
  Username      VARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL,
?>
```

is not valid PHP starting at "CREATE TABLE..."

And besides a lot more Syntax Errors in PHP, this is not valid HTML:

```
  <input id="Continue" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" name="Continue"  
 type="submit" value="Continue" action="retropcpersonalinfo.html" method="link" </input>
```

The `<input>` tag does not have an action property nor does it have a method property. Both goes in to the `<form>` tag and method is an ENUM with only `POST` or `GET`.

Comment: file inclusion way as well . `dbstuff.inc
define("DBHOST", "YOURHOST");`